# Typeorm Repository ошибка в пагинации

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

В сервисе nestjs используется репозиторий:

```
constructor(
  @InjectRepository(Post) private readonly postRepository: Repository<Post>,
) {}
```

Для пагинации есть DTO:

```
export class PaginationQueryDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsPositive()
  limit?: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsPositive()
  offset?: number;
}
```

В методе используетя репозиторий:

```
findAll(paginationQuery: PaginationQueryDto) {
  const { limit, offset } = paginationQuery;
  return this.postRepository.find({ take: limit, skip: offset });
}
```

Но если в параметрах запроса не указывать `limit` и `offset`, то появляется ошибка:

```
EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column "take" was found.
    at EntityColumnNotFound.TypeORMError [as constructor] (/home/unowen/projects/microblog/src/error/TypeORMError.ts:7:9)
    at new EntityColumnNotFound (/home/unowen/projects/microblog/src/error/EntityColumnNotFound.ts:5:9)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.QueryBuilder.findColumnsForPropertyPath (/home/unowen/projects/microblog/src/query-builder/QueryBuilder.ts:976:19)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.<anonymous> (/home/unowen/projects/microblog/src/query-builder/QueryBuilder.ts:1069:68)
    at step (/home/unowen/projects/microblog/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/home/unowen/projects/microblog/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.QueryBuilder.getWhereCondition (/home/unowen/projects/microblog/src/query-builder/QueryBuilder.ts:1208:80)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.where (/home/unowen/projects/microblog/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:720:32)
    at Function.FindOptionsUtils.applyFindManyOptionsOrConditionsToQueryBuilder (/home/unowen/projects/microblog/src/find-options/FindOptionsUtils.ts:76:23)
    at EntityManager.<anonymous> (/home/unowen/projects/microblog/src/entity-manager/EntityManager.ts:733:26)
```

Comment: попробуйте написать так `{ where: {}, take: limit, skip: offset }`

Comment: @nörbörnën, да, это помогло. Но почему так происходит? Это ошибка в typeorm или @nestjs/typeorm?

Comment: если бы мне хотелось написать объяснение, а мне не хочется - я бы написал полноценный ответ. нет тут никакой ошибки, есть неопределённость в выборе поведения при исполнении самого find. посмотрите внимательно в typeorm типы FindConditions и особенно FindOptions